# Android Get VersionName in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, version

How do I get the versionName in a Fragment? The code below does not function:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
    PackageInfo pInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0);
    version = pInfo.versionName;
```

It's working fine.

Comment: Oh, so I need to call the `getActivity()` to use it in Fragments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Context reference. You can use for example the fragment's parent activity.

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```